# angularjs + bootstrap, btn in template function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I am learning angularjs and bootstrap.
It is simple, but I dont know, what I am doing wrong.
The point is to reload the page with a button, but I was not able to get inside the function, which has to reload the page.

### This is my component.js

```
        myApp.component('refreshComponent', {
        template:"<button class='btn btn-lg  btn-info' ng-click='refresh()' >Refresh </button>",
        controller: function RefreshController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          var vm = this;

          vm.refresh = function(){
             console.log("How to get here?")
             location.reload();
          }
        }
      });
```

### This is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" class="container bg-primary img-rounded">
        <h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
              <date-component></date-component>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
              <greetings-component></greetings-component>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6  text-right ">
              <refresh-component></refresh-component>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h1>
      </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>

      <script src="date.component.js"></script>
      <script src="greetings.component.js"></script>
      <script src="refresh.component.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

BTW those other componnent are working
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);`
 myApp is initialized in date.component.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you added `controllerAs: 'vm',` to your component and  `ng-click='refresh()` to `ng-click='vm.refresh()`

So your component should look like:

```
 myApp.component('refreshComponent', {
    template:"<button class='btn btn-lg  btn-info' ng-click='vm.refresh()' >Refresh </button>",
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: function RefreshController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.refresh = function(){
         console.log("How to get here?")
         location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
```

**Tip 1:**

if you use `vm`, you don't need `$scope` at all. A.e.:

```
function RefreshController($element, $attrs)
```

**Tip 2:**

If you go to obfuscate your code, worth to use `$inject` to avoid unexpected behavior:

```
 myApp.component('refreshComponent', {
    template:"<button class='btn btn-lg  btn-info' ng-click='vm.refresh()' >Refresh </button>",
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: RefreshController
  }); 


function RefreshController($element, $attrs) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.refresh = function(){
         console.log("How to get here?")
         location.reload();
      }
 }

RefreshController.$inject = ['$element', '$attrs'];
```

Comment: I did it, but I have less than 15 reputation so does not change.
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.